# How to assign "var" inside if statement

Tags: c#, linq

I need to do this:

```
var productsLocation = response.blah blah; //with linq query
var item; // even var item = null; //not valid
if(condition){
    item = productsLocation.linq query
} else {
    item = productsLocation.differentquery
}
var group = item.query;
```

Is this possible? If yes, how?

EDIT: here is my exact code:

```
var productLocation = response.productLocation.Select(p => ProductLocationStaticClass.DtoToModel(p));
var items;
if (condition)
{
    items = productLocation.Select(s => new ProductClass(s)).Where(s => categories.Contains(s.CategoryName));
} else {
    items = productLocation.Select(s => new ProductClass(s)).Where(s => categories.Contains(s.CategoryName) && stocks.Contains(s.Barcode));                        
}
```

Comment: Yes possible, as you have shown it

Comment: @Sajeetharan: Wrong. You can't initialize a implicit typed variable like 'var item' with 'nothing' How should the compiler know, what type you want to initialize? Initialize the item with some type you know.

Comment: @Sajeetharan Should it throw an error "Implicitly-typed local variables must be initialized"? Which the compiler don't know what type it is

Comment: The compiler needs to know what type the variable is when it is declared. If it can't infer that (and because you assign it later, it can't) then you have to be explicit about it. So it probably needs to be `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` is the type of object the LINQ query is returning.

Comment: What about var item = (IQueryable) null; ? Or whatever common type differentquery and linqquery have.

Comment: Just change `stocks.Contains(s.Barcode)` to `(condition || stocks.Contains(s.Barcode))` and you don't even need the if/else block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all get your `response` variable type, then initialize `'item'` variable as IEnumarable where T is same as `response` variable type

```
var productsLocation = response.productLocation.Select(p => ProductLocationStaticClass.DtoToModel(p));
IEnumerable<ProductClass> item;  
if (condition)
{
    items = productLocation.Select(s => new ProductClass(s)).Where(s => categories.Contains(s.CategoryName));
} 
else 
{
    items = productLocation.Select(s => new ProductClass(s)).Where(s => categories.Contains(s.CategoryName) && stocks.Contains(s.Barcode));             
}
var group = item.Where(condition);
```

Comment: I added an edit to the question , can you please check? Thanks

Comment: IEnumerable<T> : T should be ProductClass type

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely at the logic, you notice you don't actually even need the `if` block.  The whole thing can be written in one expression as follows:

```
var items = productLocation
  .Select(s => new ProductClass(s))
  .Where(s => categories.Contains(s.CategoryName) && (condition || stocks.Contains(s.Barcode)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `IEnumerable` interface in this way:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

---

```
List<string> products = new List<string>() { "First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth" };
IEnumerable item;
var condition = false;
if (condition)
{
    item = products.Select(x=>x);
}
else
{
    item = products.Where(x => x.StartsWith("F"));
}
var group =  item.Cast<string>().Where(/*...Here your conditions...*/)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I cant call "var group = item.Where()"

Comment: @NicoTing you can do it after `Cast` as item will be `IEnumerable` while LINQ is working on `IEnumerable<T>`. You can do the following `var group = item.Cast<string>.Where();`

Comment: I added an edit to the question , can you please check? Thanks